# Conditional formatting to alter the displayed content of a cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to compare the current grade of my class to their target grade. I felt the best approach was to use conditional formatting to look up the grades currently achieved and compare this to their target using the following equations;

```
=SEARCH(E2,"ABCDEFGU")<>SEARCH(C2,"ABCDEFGU")
```

To return Green for above their target (Only the greater than sign)

```
=SEARCH(E2,"ABCDEFGU")=SEARCH(C2,"ABCDEFGU")
```

To return Amber for on target

```
=SEARCH(E2,"ABCDEFGU")>SEARCH(C2,"ABCDEFGU")
```

To return Red for below target.

This worked fine (results [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwbB9rHFxrbSdVFrWXVlV0xtOHc/edit?usp=sharing)), until I remembered about grade A*.

After a lot of hassle I figured the easiest one to do is to get all teachers to use S instead of A* and change the `SEARCH` function to have an S at the beginning of the list.

The thing is that I know lots of teachers will forget to do this. I was hoping to use conditional formatting so that whenever somebody entered A*, it would automatically replace it with an S.

Is this possible? If so how? If not is there a solution for keeping A*, but not needed the crazily overboard equation I had been using before.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 4<sup>th</sup> condition, in which if cell E2 (or E3,E4) is equal to a*, then color with green.

Go to: "Conditional Formatting" --> "Format only cells that contain", and then:

set Cell value - equal to - a*. See picture below:

[image]

You will end up with something like below:

[image]

<sub>I used Excel 2007</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could warp your existing green condition in "OR(...,E2="A*")

```
=OR(SEARCH(E2,"SABCDEFGU")<SEARCH(C2,"SABCDEFGU"),E2="A*")
```